# Read Metadata Dynamically in SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a requirement where I have execute a MYSQL procedure (procedure name is same across all the sites) for different sites, I have a For each loop which get the server details and database details and within the Foreach Loop container I have dataflow task, in the data flow task I created a source connection for  a MySql connection and calling the stored procedure like below,

CALL spITProd( '2022-09-25 20:04:22.847000000', '2022-10-25 20:04:22.847000000' );

This gives different metadata for different sites, to be precise first 16 columns are same for all the sites and after that  number of columns and column names can vary, my requirement is to store first 16 columns in a destination table and all other columns in a different table by unpivoting them, I was able to achieve this for one site as shown below SSIS data flow task,

[image]

I want to automate this for process for all the sites, I know I can create multiple data flow tasks but that's not what I want to do, when source connects to the new site it fails as it encounters new metadata (as I said number of columns and column name  changes after first 16  columns), Please suggest any ideas on how to dynamically read the columns from the procedure. I don't have any permission son the MYSQL database it is managed by the vendor I just have permission to the call the procedure, I tried to store the data into **System.Object** variable but I am not sure how to use that later as I cant create a temp table on destination using that, Appreciate any ideas on how to handle this requirement.

Mentioned the details above

Comment: SSIS doesn't do dynamic metadata very well. There are workarounds but they are painful. I solve this by not using SSIS at all, just exporting data from MySQL to a flat file then importing that as _one_ column into a staging table and shredding it up using a stored procedure. SSIS might be useful for looping through MySQL Server and runnig a command to dump data to a text file

Comment: Either that or you have a different task per site, but that is only practical if there are a finite list of column combinations

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid make sense, Thank you for taking time to reply to my question, appreciate it.